# ExtJS - center items in button group

Tags: extjs, extjs4, markup

I'm not sure how to go about this, `buttonAlign: 'center'` nor `pack: 'center'` are working. Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3Ytp9/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [layout](http://docs.extjs.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.container.ButtonGroup-cfg-layout) property of buttongroup:

```
    layout: {
        type: 'vbox',
        align: 'center'
    }
```

See forked fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1cm

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using a toolbar in the bottom of your panel?

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1c0 (without mvc pattern)

You can also use something like this:

```
        dockedItems: [{
        xtype: 'toolbar',
        layout: {
            pack: 'center'
        },
        defaultButtonUI: 'default', // get default look and feel
        dock: 'bottom',
        items: [{
            xtype: 'button',
            width: 200,           
            text: 'Download to Excel',

        },{
            xtype: 'button',
            width: 200,           
            text: 'Another action',

        }]
```

Best Regards.

Comment: Hm, any way to center them without using a docked toolbar?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Ext.onReady(function() {
  var panel = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    title: 'Button group',
    border: true,
    layout: {
        align: 'middle',
        pack: 'center',
        type: 'hbox'
    },
    width: 500,
    items: [{
        xtype: 'buttongroup',
        columns: 1,
        items: [{
            xtype: 'button',
            text: 'Go'
        }, {
            xtype: 'button',
            text: 'Reset'
        }]
    }]
 });
});
```

To have the buttons side by side, remove `columns:1` - also note that the Ext JS implementation on JSFiddle is terrible, so dont rely on it too much.